# Firestore query snapshot empty after startAfter method

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore

I am testing Firestore queries for pagination. I have written 500 mock documents in batch to my Firestore  db collection. When I tested tested the query, I am getting valid query snapshot only for initial query. If I use start after with my document snapshot, I get an empty document list.

Below is my test query method I used with delays to verify if pagination might work.

```
    private var snap:DocumentSnapshot? = null
    private val list:MutableList<Item> = ArrayList()
    private var isInitial = true

    private suspend fun queryList(){
        var q:Query = Firebase.firestore.collection("trial2/user_items/items")
        for(i in 1..5){
            q = if(snap == null){
                q.orderBy("creation",Query.Direction.ASCENDING).limit(10)
            }else{
                q.startAfter(snap).limit(10)
            }
            val result = q.get().await()
            list.addAll(result.toObjects(Item::class.java))
            snap = result.documents[0]
            delay(500)
            isInitial = false
            
        }
        for(i in list){
          println(i)
        }
    }
```

All documents contain the field "creation" which is a long value holding the System.currentTimeMillis() value.

May I know If i am committing a mistake. I am following the method from [Alex Mamo pagination guide](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-implement-pagination-in-firestore-using-jetpack-compose-76b4c0b5acd5)

I tried with query snapshot and got an error that the task is not completed yet.

Comment: The linked [articlee](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-implement-pagination-in-firestore-using-jetpack-compose-76b4c0b5acd5) uses [Paging v3 library](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/paging/v3-paged-data) for pagination. I cannot see in your code something related to that. Besides that, if the app crashes, there is a stack trace. Please look that up on logcat, and add it to your question.

Comment: Hello @AlexMamo Thank you for your reply. I have fixed the issue with non null assertion operator. While using mySnapshotKey!! on the startAfter method fixed the issue.

Comment: @AlexMamo I do have an issue with Paging 3 testing. I am unit testing the flow from Pager using the guide https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/paging/test . While I use asSnapshot() method, the lambda supplied to the asSnapshot method is not reachable, I used the debugger to verify. My code is on this paste link https://pastebin.com/MQ9FUgAe